# AttributeError: MIMEText instance has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python

I am trying use smtplib to send attachments. but for some reasons I get this traceback. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import smtplib
import getpass
from email import Encoders
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText

fromaddr = "<email>"
toaddr = "<email>"

username = "email"
password = getpass.getpass("Email password : ")
filename = 'test.txt'
f = file(filename)
msg = MIMEMultipart()
attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename = filename)
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = 'Test'
msg.attach(MIMEText(attachment))
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,msg.as_string())
server.quit()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./emailte.py", line 21, in <module>
    msg.attach(MIMEText(attachment))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 226, in set_payload
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 268, in set_charset
    cte(self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/encoders.py", line 73, in encode_7or8bit
    orig.encode('ascii')
AttributeError: MIMEText instance has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Read the traceback. It points out the line where the error occurs. Read the documentation for the things that line calls, and you'll see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Your `attachment` is already a `MIMEText` object. So, why do that again in `mag.attach()`? Have you tried `msg.attach(attachment)`?

Comment: Thanks user2357112. I should have done that before posting here.

Answer (score 0):

From @shaktimaan comment

> Your attachment is already a MIMEText object. So, why do that again in mag.attach()? Have you tried msg.attach(attachment)?